# calling dynamically to class method based on command line arguments

Tags: python, string

I need to call the class methods based on the command line argument

```
params = sys.argv[1].split('.')

print params

['Abc', 'test']

suite.addTest(params[0](params[1]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "policy.py", line 407, in <module>
    suite.addTest(params[0](params[1]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is their any way to call a class method.

Comment: Where is `Abc` class defined?

Comment: I tried the globals() by using like this suite.addTest(globals()[params[0]](globals()[params[1]])) i got below error " KeyError: 'test' "

Comment: See my answer below, don't use globals() twice. Either params is a parameter to calling the class or it's an attribute in which case you would do `TestClass = globals()[params[0]]` and then `getattr(TestClass, params[1])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `params[0]` is still the string `'Abc'`. You need to transform it into a class that you can call.

Suppose class `Abc` is in module `foo`. Then you can do this--

```
import foo

MyTestClass = getattr(foo, params[0])

suite.addTest(MyTestClass(params[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to do it is using `eval` which will take the string and evaluate it in the current namespace. But `eval` is evil since your program input could look something like:

```python
eval("os.remove('/')")
```

just as an example. Python also has a dictionary of the globals you can use this:

```
TestClass = globals()[params[0]]
suite.addTest(TestClass(params[1])
```